# explain largestDivisible code from the Learn You A Haskell for Great Good tutorial

Tags: haskell

```
largestDivisible :: (Integral a) => a
largestDivisible = head (filter p [100000,99999..])
    where p x = x `mod` 3829 == 0
```

If p x equals True,

does

```
head (filter p [100000,99999..])
```

become

```
head (filter True)
```

?

What list is being filtered for True?

While this code is being run, what are p and x's values?

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible—I'm not sure what you're actually *asking*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filter p [100000,99999..]` calculates the list including all numbers descending from 100000 for which p returns true. `head` then takes the first of that list, effectively giving you the largest number x below 100000, for which `p x` returns true, i.e. for which `` x `mod` 3829 `` is 0.

> What values are in p and x?

p is a function that takes one argument called `x` and returns true iff `` x `mod` 3829 == 0 ``. `x` is the argument given to the function. Since you use p as an argument to filter, this means that each element of the list `[100000,99999..]` will be given to p in turn, until p returns true for the first time (it won't try any more elements because by using head, you're only requesting one element, so it only calculates one).

Comment: @Deliriumtremens: `p x` returns true if (and only if) ``x `mod` 3829 == 0``, i.e. if x is divisible by 3829 without remainder.

Answer (score 3):

`p` is a function defined by `` p x = x `mod` 3829 == 0 ``.

`x` is a variable in the `p` function. `filter` calls `p` with elements from the list `[100000,99999..]`, so `x` will be one of the members of that list.

`filter p [100000,99999..]` is the same as `(filter p) [100000,99999..]`, *not* `filter (p [100000,99999..])`. So `p` is *not* called with `[100000,99999..]` as an argument (and it would be a type error anyway).